# Web Compiler by Mads Kristensen extension - VS Code Mac download

Tags: visual-studio

I'm having troubles finding the following extensions on MAC:

- Web Compiler by Mads Kristensen.
- Typescript Definition Generator by Mads Kristensen

They seem to be only available for windows.

Does anyone with a Mac know how I can install these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you’re looking for doesn’t exist.

Web Compiler is for Visual Studio (the IDE), not *Visual Studio Code* (the editor).

Comment: Thank you. I finally realised there was a difference between the IDE and the editor. Do you know how I can get the Web Compiler on the IDE for MAC?

Comment: @hoolisoft You can't because Visual Studio 2019 is not available for macOS. Also, macOS and "Mac" is never rendered in all-caps. "MAC" typically refers to your MAC Address.